# HtmlUnit throws ambiguous String error in Processing

Tags: java, processing, htmlunit

I am trying to write code in Processing (basically Java) that will get the information from the table here: http://science.nasa.gov/iSat/iSAT-text-only/

I have not started writing the code specific to the table yet because I can't even get this to run. I get the error "type String is ambiguous." I cannot find any duplicate of String nor can I think of any other reason for this error.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import java.net.*;

WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
try {
    java.lang.String url = "http://science.nasa.gov/iSat/iSAT-text-only/";
    Page page = client.getPage(url);
    println(page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
}
catch(IOException e) {
    println("oops!");
}
```

UPDATE:
I modified the code slightly and got it to get the information I want using the following code in eclipse:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String url = "http://science.nasa.gov/iSat/iSAT-text-only/";
HtmlPage page = null;
try {
    page = (HtmlPage) client.getPage(url);
} catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
System.out.print(page.asXml());
```

but it still throws the ambiguous String error in Processing.

Comment: What exact line is the error on?

Comment: None. No matter how I rearrange the code, it just highlights the last line (in this case, the bracket)

Comment: @SaJaK What version of Processing are you using ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza 2.2.1

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza It gives the same error in 3.0b5 for me as well

Comment: Strange, I just tested with 2.2.1 using your first snipped and it does display the content (after a few warnings):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely, manually importing java.lang.String fixed the error.